# Comment search plugin

Tags: filters, comments, search, hooks, actions

I want to develop a plugin which places a search input field above the first comment on the post pages, filters the comments below that post, and only shows the comments which include the string that has been entered.

Now, doing this in normal PHP and AJAX would be no problem, but I can't find how to place that form, and more importantly, while I can find a lot about how to alter the comments before they are sent into the database, how do I filter the comments (with AJAX) before they are shown below a post?

Edit:
From what i've found, the hooks I would need to use are `pre_get_comments` or `get_comments`. 
But if I try:

```
add_action( 'get_comments', 'add_input_field_comments');
function add_input_field_comments( $comments )
{
    $inputField = '<input type="text" name="searchInput">';

    //either
    $comments .= $inputField;
    //or 
    array_push($comments($inputField));

    return $comments;
    // they return nothing
}
```

Which is the case for both the hooks I try. 
Am I still using the wrong hooks or do I need to return the input through another way?